# React-Apollo - render getting called before getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a component that includes a verification form for a user. This component runs a graphql query upon mount. In the Verification component, I need to use the data from the graphql query to set the state so I can use it to update any values, and then submit them with the form. I have since learned about `getDerivedStateFromProps` and that is working to populate a new state from that data. But, the data isn't available in the DOM. It's as if `render` gets called before `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Here is the component:

```
class Verification extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            company: {
                legalName: ''
            },
            openCorporatesCompany: {}
        };
    }

    handleLegalNameChange = (legalName) => {
        let company = _.cloneDeep(this.state.company);
        company.legalName = legalName;
        this.setState({
            company
        })
    };

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(next, prev) {
        let newState = _.cloneDeep(prev);
        let {openCorporates: {getEntityAttribute}} = next;

        if (getEntityAttribute && getEntityAttribute.value) {
            let openCorporatesCompany = JSON.parse(getEntityAttribute.value);
            let company = _.cloneDeep(newState.company);
            company.legalName = openCorporatesCompany.name;
            newState.openCorporatesCompany = openCorporatesCompany;
            newState.company = company;

            return newState;
        }

        return null;
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);

        return (
                    <Input
                        label='Legal Name'
                        placeholder='Legal entity name...'
                        type='text'
                        subtext='Use the name your customers or clients will recognize'
                        onChange={this.handleLegalNameChange}
                        value={this.state.legalName}
                    />
        );
    }
}

export const VerificationContainer = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
    graphql(GetEntityAttributeQuery, {
        name: "openCorporates",
        options: (props) => ({
            variables: {
                entityId: props.currentEntity.id,
                type: EntityAttributes.TypeOpenCorporates
            }
        })
    })
)(Verification);
```

The console output of the `console.log(this.state)` in `render` looks like this:

[image: console log]

As you can see, the field gets updated in state in `company.legalName`. But, it never gets populated in the Input box:

[image]

Why does the input not get updated with the new state? It's as if the render gets called before `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your struggle with react and component updating, but I guess there's no bullet proof to get rid of it;  80% I guess you should try any of the different life cycle methods. Back in the day there was **componentWillReceiveProps** for async calls but since it's been marked unsafe (I guess) you should try **getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)**

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  console.log("*************** PROPS:",  props);

  let { openCorporates: { getEntityAttribute  } } = props;

  if (getEntityAttribute  &&  getEntityAttribute.value) {
      let openCorporatesCompany = JSON.parse(getEntityAttribute.value);
      let company = _.cloneDeep(this.state.company);

      company.legalName = openCorporatesCompany.name;
      this.setState({
          openCorporatesCompany,
          company
      })
  }
}
```

Take into account I haven't run the snippet.

Comment: I get this error when adding that: `Warning: Verification: getDerivedStateFromProps() is defined as an instance method and will be ignored. Instead, declare it as a static method.`

Comment: lol sorry, add "static" on the signature, e.i.  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {...

Comment: How should I successfully use that method? It says I need to return an object. Is the `state` object passed in, the `this.state` object from the component? Do I just mutate that object and then return it as the new state?

Comment: sorry, i have while without using react, but in essence you should compare the arguments, in this case next and prev, for the value
if(next.openCorporates.value !== prev.openCorporates.value){
     return { openCorporates: next.openCorporates};
  }
  else return null;

[as in this post](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607)

Comment: Where does next and prev come from? The method signature only has props and state. Also, this is working about half of the time. If I print out `this.state` in the render function, it shows the data every time. But, sometimes the components on the page don't have the data. It's as if those child component's render is getting called before getDerivedStateFromProps from the parent component.

Comment: @JonStevens the next and prev are just convenience names. In my example I copied the signature out of the documentation. When implementing the method you are moving from one state (prev) to another  state (next) so you should compare and return accordingly; usually next is the state you desire. If it had missing fields maybe that's why. So, console log both next and prev and  build up your object (e.i. newState). Hopefully it'll do the trick

Comment: Same result. Still only updates the DOM with those data fields sometimes.

Comment: can you use a snippet of how the files are looking now?

Comment: What snippet are you looking for?

Comment: the one that is not showing the data properly, the class that contains the getDerivedStateFromProps in this case...

Comment: I have updated my question as I feel it's a new problem now.

Comment: sorry about that, seems like you must call componentDidUpdate() after every getDerivedStateFromProps in case you want to  perform state changes. [I have updated your code](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/301749/)

Answer (score 1):

This ended up doing the trick, thanks to @Charlie's answer:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    let newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
    let { openCorporates: { getEntityAttribute  } } = props;

    if (getEntityAttribute  &&  getEntityAttribute.value) {
        let openCorporatesCompany = JSON.parse(getEntityAttribute.value);
        let company = _.cloneDeep(newState.company);
        company.legalName = openCorporatesCompany.name;
        newState.openCorporatesCompany = openCorporatesCompany;
        newState.company = company;
    }

    return newState;
}
```